# Service does not send data

Tags: java, android

when the screen is locked on and off, then the service ceases to send data to the database Mysql. How to fix it ?2 days I can not find the answer,
added permission to wakelock
Explain to me why this is happening
Thats my code :

```
public class GpsService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 123123;
   private static final String LOGSERVICE = "#######";
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
   String urlAddress="*****";
    String adress ="https://www.google.az/";
    String number = "Example2";
    String id="2";
    String status;
    String mlatitude, mlogtud;
    String times;
    TimerTask task;
    Timer timer;
    Date now;



        public GpsService() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "MyWakelockTag");

        super.onCreate();
        wakeLock.acquire();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        Notification notification;
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        notification = builder.build();
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"servis leavle");
       task=new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //SimpleDateFormat example - Date with timezone information
                Date today = new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
                status=date.toString();
                Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"my new time +   =  "+status);

             //   Log.d(LOGSERVICE,times );
                Sender s=new Sender(getApplicationContext(),number,urlAddress,mlatitude,mlogtud,id,status);
                s.execute();



            }
        };
        timer=new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,5*1000,8*1000);
        wakeLock.release();


    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(LOGSERVICE, "onStartCommand");

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"servis destroy");
      timer.cancel();

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(LOGSERVICE, "onConnected" + bundle);

        Location l = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (l != null) {
            Log.i(LOGSERVICE, "lat " + l.getLatitude());
            Log.i(LOGSERVICE, "lng " + l.getLongitude());


        }

        startLocationUpdate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(LOGSERVICE, "onConnectionSuspended " + i);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          mlatitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
       mlogtud = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

      /*  new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
             Sender s=new Sender(getApplicationContext(),number,urlAddress,mlatitude,mlogtud,id,status);
                s.execute();

                Log.i(LOGSERVICE,"Location onnnn " );
            }
        },10*1000, 5*1000);*/
        LatLng mLocation = (new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
 }
    private void initLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(12000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    }
    private void startLocationUpdate() {
        initLocationRequest();
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    private void stopLocationUpdate() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);

    }
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
}
```

My main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
    static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private FusedLocationProviderApi locationProvider = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private static final String LOGSERVICE = "#######";
    Button  btnStart, btnStop;
    TextView textTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         btnStart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart) ;
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,GpsService.class));

                Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"Starting Service");

            }
        });
        btnStop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStop) ;
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,GpsService.class));
                Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"Stop Service");

            }
        });



        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);



    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        requestLocationUpdates();

    }

    private void requestLocationUpdates() {


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "permission was granted, :)",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    requestLocationUpdates();
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "permission denied, ...:(",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {


    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    /*    Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"latitud" + location.getLatitude());
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"lotitude" + location.getLongitude());
        myLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        myLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        lat.setText(String.valueOf(myLatitude));
        lot.setText(String.valueOf(myLongitude));*/


    }
    public void settingsrequest()
    {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(1 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
// Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        requestLocationUpdates();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Gps turn on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        settingsrequest();//keep asking if imp or do whatever
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.connect();
        settingsrequest();



        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"onSTart" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            requestLocationUpdates();
        }
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"onResume" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
      //  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"onPause" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
       // googleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"onStop" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOGSERVICE,"onDestroy" );
    }
}
```

Comment: You could find interesting to read about [Doze](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#doze) this could be your case and some solution could be [in the optimizing an app for Doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#assessing_your_app) page

Comment: This post may help as well https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/94jCkmG4jff

Comment: как это исправить? можешь мне помочь??

Comment: This is not really [mcve] but I see you didn't use my answer. The lock is still release to soon.

Answer (score 1):

You did not use the Wakelock correctly.

```
public void onCreate() {
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "MyWakelockTag");

    super.onCreate();
    wakeLock.acquire();
    ...
    task=new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           ....
        }
    };
    timer=new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,5*1000,8*1000);
    wakeLock.release();
}
```

You are releasing the lock at the end of the `onCreate` method so the `Task` doesn't hold any lock at all. You should release it when you stop the scheduled task only.

Note in the comment the existence of Doze that ignore the WakeLock after some inactivity.

Comment: This is not Doze for the moment, you simply release the lock where you want to keep it. But you can [adapt the app](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#assessing_your_app) to Doze.

Comment: @elik Could you edit your code to be a [mcve], probably just need a Task with a log to see if it is running or not. EDIT : **please clean the comments that are not needed ;)**

Comment: Ok sir üait minute please

Comment: @elik I will check that later ;)